# Apache virtualhost: requests to domain are served from default directory

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

**Requests to my domain leanback.eu are served from the default page (/var/www/default), and not from /var/www/leanback_eu. How is this possible?** Other vhosts are working fine. The hostname of my machine is leanback.eu...

000-default:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/default/
        <Directory /var/www/default/>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_default.log

        # debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_default.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

leanback_eu:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@leanback.eu
    ServerName leanback.eu
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/leanback_eu/"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error_leanback_eu.log"
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_leanback_eu.log combined


    <Directory "/var/www/leanback_eu/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/leanback_eu/stats>
                Options Indexes
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

$ sudo apache2 -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
default server leanback.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:2)
port 80 namevhost leanback.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:2)
port 80 namevhost kexx.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/kexx_net:77)
port 80 namevhost leanback.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/leanback_eu:1)
```

It might be zomething very simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first virtual host container not having a `ServerName` directive is causing it to be a catch all. Add a name for that (whatever default you want), but change the enclosure to read `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` instead of `*:80` and you should be good to go. It will still be the default, but now the others will match too instead of getting stuck on the match all host that didn't have a name.

Comment: I added `ServerName foobar.com` as I have currently set up all my domains nicely. It seems to work fine now. Is this a good way to go?

Comment: I would recommend using a real valid name, like `hostname.otherdomain.com` or whatever your reverse dns entry works out to.